# Javascript Equivalent of a cURL request

Tags: javascript, php, curl

Is there a way to complete this cURL request in Javascript?

```
curl -X POST https://api.mongohq.com/databases/vehicles/collections/rockets/documents?_apikey=12345 \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"document" : {"_id" : "bottle", "pilot_name" : "Elton John"}, "safe" : true }'
```

The below code is as close as I've been able to get, but it returns {"error":"Failed to create mongohq::api::document"}.

```
function postsBeaconMessage (postTo, beaconMessage , targetFrame) {
    var beacon = document.createElement("form");
    beacon.method="POST";
    beacon.action = postTo;
    //beacon.target = targetFrame;

    var message = document.createElement("input") ;
    message.setAttribute("type", "hidden") ;
    message.setAttribute("name", "document") ;
    message.setAttribute("value", beaconMessage);
    beacon.appendChild(message) ;

    beacon.submit();
}
```

I get a 500 error when I execute this, but the cURL works fine.  I assume it's an issue with  setting the content type.  Is there a way to set the content type in the form or post object?  It seems mongohq requires an explicit content type declaration.

I don't have access to change the same-origin policy on the server, and I'm pretty sure I won't be able to execute PHP.

Any thoughts would be helpful.  I'm dead in the water here.

Comment: wait, have you tried plain old ajax?

Comment: Yeah.  I get server origin issues when I use that.  This at least gets to the server, but I don't think the request is formed correctly.

Comment: Specifically: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load api.mongohq.com/databases/tvplay/collections/beacon/…. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers." I'm not sure why I get through to the server when I use straight Javascript

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you are sending a `POST` request to `https://api.mongohq.com/databases/vehicles/collections/rockets/documents?_apikey=12345` URL with `{"document" : {"_id" : "bottle", "pilot_name" : "Elton John"}, "safe" : true }` data and the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`.

This can be achieved in JavaScript by doing the following

```js
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
 //  Check if request is completed
 if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
  // Do what needs to be done here
  console.log(xhr.response);
    }
}

// Set the request URL and request method
xhr.open("POST", "https://api.mongohq.com/databases/vehicles/collections/rockets/documents?_apikey=12345");

// Set the `Content-Type` Request header
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

// Send the requst with Data
xhr.send('{"document" : {"_id" : "bottle", "pilot_name" : "Elton John"}, "safe" : true }');
```